# HP Script Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my script at Unity. I apply this script to my character and nothing happens when it reaches the collider, no HP is taken.

```
public int HP = 100;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
}
void LoseHP(Collider col)
{
    if(col.tag == "trap")
    {
        HP -= 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert of Unity but I'd use the method OnCollisionEnter that allows you to know if your object has begun to touch another rigidbody/collider. Here the [link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)

Or another solution could be that you check in the Update() method if your object has been touched from another rigidbody. If the statement is true, call your LoaseHP(...) method.

Comment: Yes. Just changed the name of my method to OnTriggerEnter and it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

also i'd consider using `FixedUpdate()` method if you want to increment a players health on being hit. `Update()` method may be called to often if you're not going to use the `OnCollisionEnter` method